# Infimum of $n$-th root of $n$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Let  $A = \left \{ \sqrt[n]{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right \}$. I need to find and prove the infimum of $A$.

Because $n \in \mathbb{N},$ we can know for sure that $\sqrt[n]{n} \geq 1$. (Does that need a deeper proof?)

Then to prove that $1$ is the infimum, for $\forall \varepsilon>0$, I need to find a certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that makes $$\sqrt[n]{n} < 1 + \varepsilon$$

How do I "engineer" that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

What's the trick? Raising $\sqrt[n]{n} < 1 + \varepsilon $ to the power of $n$ doesn't really help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$?

Comment: Hmmm... $1$ is in $A$ hence $\inf A=1$, end of proof.

Answer (score 1):

The infimum of $A$ is $1$ because $1\in A$ (just take $n=1$) and $n>1\implies\sqrt[n]n>1$.

On the other hand, you can write $\sqrt[n]n$ as $1+\varepsilon_n$ and then\begin{align}n&=\sqrt[n]n^n\\&=(1+\varepsilon_n)^n\\&=1+n\varepsilon_n+\frac{n(n-1)}2{\varepsilon_n}^2+\cdots\\&>\frac{n(n-1)}2{\varepsilon_n}^2\end{align}and therefore$$\varepsilon_n<\sqrt{\frac2{n-1}},$$if $n>1$.

Comment: That's not enough. I need to prove that for each $ \varepsilon > 0 $ there is $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ that makes $n > $ some epsilon that we render..

Comment: What do you think now?

Comment: Well, it seems better but could I please get an explanation do what you've done?

Comment: @Eran19978 I am sorry, but I don't see what is there to explain. Could you be more specific?

Comment: If you keep the $1$ and only drop the $n\epsilon_n$, you get the slightly better inequality $\epsilon_n\lt\sqrt{2/n}$ for $n\gt1$ (by canceling an $n-1$ instead of an $n$).

Comment: @BarryCipra Nice observation!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I understand that you developed $ (1+\varepsilon)^{n} $ into its "binomial" form if you will, but why did you decide to "dig" $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}*\varepsilon{^2}$ ?

Comment: Because it works. I could have used$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6{\varepsilon_n}^3$$instead and it would have worked too, but why would I do that when $\frac{n(n-1)}2{\varepsilon_n}^2$ is enough?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos To be more specific, I understand why $ (1+\varepsilon)^{n} > \frac{n(n-1)}{2}*\varepsilon{^2} $

But how do you determine that $ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}*\varepsilon{^2} > n $ ?

Comment: Because$$n=1+n\varepsilon_n+\frac{n(n-1)}2{\varepsilon_n}^2+\cdots$$and all terms in this sum are greater than $0$. Therefore, $n$ is greater than *each* of these terms.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh, I didn't see that you defined $\sqrt[n]n$ to be $ 1+\varepsilon_n $

What allows you to do that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos its kinda odd, because I need to show $ \sqrt[n]{n} < 1 + \varepsilon $ 

Then why would you define $ \sqrt[n]{n} = 1 + \varepsilon $

Comment: I dont understand your doubt. I *wrote* $\sqrt[n]n$ as $1+\varepsilon_n$. In other words, I *defined* $\varepsilon_n$ as $\sqrt[n]n-1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Last question: Could I just Assume that if i find n that makes: $ n< \frac{n(n-1)}{2}*\varepsilon{^2}$ that would automatically apply for $n<(1+\varepsilon){^n}$

Comment: Yes, since $\frac{n(n-1)}2\varepsilon^2\leqslant(1+\varepsilon)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$ (which immediately leads to $\sqrt[n]{n} < 1+\varepsilon$ from the definition of limit), then try the following trick ...

---

$$n=e^{\ln{n}} \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\frac{\ln{n}}{n}}$$
It is not too difficult to show that $0<\frac{\ln{n}}{n} < 1$ and thus, we can apply [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$$e^{\frac{\ln{n}}{n}}=(1+e-1)^{\frac{\ln{n}}{n}}\leq 1+\frac{(e-1)\ln{n}}{n}$$
or 
$$\sqrt[n]{n}\leq 1+\frac{(e-1)\ln{n}}{n}$$
and because $\frac{n}{\ln{n}}>\sqrt{n}$ for $n>1$ we have
$$\sqrt[n]{n}\leq 1+\frac{(e-1)\ln{n}}{n}<1+\frac{e-1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
you can squeeze $\frac{e-1}{\sqrt{n}} < \varepsilon$ now.

---

Now, why

> $\frac{n}{\ln{n}}>\sqrt{n}$ for $n>1$

Because, using **induction**
$$\frac{2}{\ln{2}} > \sqrt{2},\space \frac{3}{\ln{3}} > \sqrt{3},\space \frac{4}{\ln{4}} > \sqrt{4}$$
and $$\frac{n}{\ln{n}}>\sqrt{n} \iff 
\color{red}{\sqrt{n} > \ln{n}} \iff 
\sqrt{n} + \ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} > \ln{n} + \ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\ln{(n+1)}$$
using $\ln{(1+x)}<x$ from [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
$$\color{red}{\sqrt{n+1}>}\sqrt{n} +\frac{1}{n}>\sqrt{n} + \ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} >\color{red}{\ln{(n+1)}}$$
for $n\geq 5$